# Why does blender keep rotating off center on objects

Tags: interface

I want to rotate around an object and keep the object in the center but it won't keep it in the center. The only thing that fixes it is to put preferences back to default but it just comes back later and for no reason. Annoying!
[image]

Comment: maybe numpad "."    to center on it?

Comment: That's what I'm doing, it doesn't stay centered

Comment: Could it be you moved the cube in edit mode, so the pivot point of the cube is now outside the cube itself?

Comment: Check out the "Orbit and Pan" options inside the navigation preferences. Looks like you have Orbit around unchecked or Auto Depth ?

Comment: press `.` in numpad as lemon said and `~` key and selecting `view selected` or simply press `F3` and type `view selected`

Comment: @Gorgious Unchecking auto-depth in Orbit and Pan options fixed it for me — thank you so much! This had been driving me nuts for days